# How do I convert a list in a .txt file to a list in Processing (python)?

Tags: python, processing

I'm running into an issue with my homework assignment.
In a text file, there is the following:

```
ignored = ["the", "a", "an", "i", "me", "you", "with", "this"]
```

(the actual contents are much longer, but I shortened it for simplicity.)

I want the list shown in the .txt file to become a list in my Processing app.

I've tried using .strip and .split to make it work:

```
size(500,500)
ignored = []
g = open("ignored.txt", "r")

for line in g:
    line = line.strip('ignored')
    line= line.strip()
    line = line.strip("=")
    line = line.strip()

    line = line.strip("][")

    line = line.split(", ")

    print(line)
    ignored.append(line)

ignored.pop()
print(ignored)
```

I've tried many combinations of what to .strip or .split, but my output from print has always been this or something similar.

```
[['"the"', '"a"', '"an"', '"i"', '"me"', '"you"', '"with"', '"this"']]
```

I would like my final list to be missing the extra quotes and brackets.  Something like:
["the", "a", "an", "i", "me", "you", "with", "this"]

I cannot finagle a way to make this work, and I'm thinking there is an easier way.

I cannot import anything, and I'm using the latest version of Processing.
For context (if necessary):
My ultimate goal is to take the words from the list "ignored" and remove those words from another list.

Let me know what, if any, other info you need to help me out.  Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not a Python developer but if I were you I would look for functions that remove characters from strings? In Java there's a handy `replace()` function. Does Python have something similar?

Comment: Ultimately, I want the contents of the list in the .txt file to be the contents of the list in processing.

Comment: Yes @Kevin, in python there is a replace function string.replace(']','') and I posted an answer. I think is what Tshering needs. Unfortunately someone didn't like the answer...

Comment: Can you write your final file, as an example?

Comment: @F.Lira - it should look as you suggested in your answer at the end.  I found Grismar's second approach to be the most useful as it simply took the line as and executed it as a command, itself.  This didn't require me to import anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the file you're loading has actual Python code in it, one way to get it would be to copy or rename it and just import it. Obviously not something that's generally recommended, if fact it's a bit of a bodge, but the assignment seems to assume you'd do something like it in this case.

```
import shutil

shutil.copy('ignored.txt', 'ignored.py')
from ignored import ignored

print(ignored)
```

Apart from being unsafe, this has the downside of telling you it can't find the ignored module from editors that check these things, like most IDEs will. Another simple solution, but also not very safe, is to evaluate the contents of the file as Python without importing it.

```
ignored = []

with open('ignored.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    exec(content)

print(ignored)
```

A safer and arguably better solution would be to parse the contents of the file and only select the elements you're after. But instead of doing that manually, like your example, you could use a regular expression to get the content you need - assuming it only contains a line like the one you provided:

```
import re

with open('ignored.txt', 'r') as f:
    content = f.read()
    ignored = [match.group(1) for match in re.finditer('[\'"](.*?)[\'"]', content)]

print(ignored)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use regex (`import re`) :

```
my_list = re.findall(r'"(\w+)"', line)
ignored.append(my_list)
```

With this, you get a list for each line in your `for` loop. Or, you can go like this :

```
ignored = re.findall(r'"(\w+)"', g.read())
```

With this simple line, you can get a list of everything between `""` in your file.

Comment: Can be shortened to `re.findall(r'"(\w+)"', line)`

Comment: Thanks, edited to make it more simple (can return the whole list for all the file) and added your improvement too

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
ignored = []
g = open("text.txt", "r")

for line in g:
    start_index = line.find('[') + 1
    end_index = line.find(']')
    l = line[start_index:end_index]
    l = l.replace('"', '')
    l = l.split()
    ignored.extend(l)
print(ignored)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly simple with this code:

```
import ast
with open("ignored.txt", "r") as f:
    f = f.read().strip("ignored = ")

    print(ast.literal_eval(f))
```

`Out[0]: ['the', 'a', 'an', 'i', 'me', 'you', 'with', 'this']`

Note it's usually better, and cleaner looking, to use `with open()`, as it automatically closes your file freeing up any wasted memory after you're done using the file in question. Else, make sure to run `f.close()` when you're done reading or writing to your file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you just need to use strip again to remove the quote from the text file.

Also, it might be less coding to use find() to locate the [] from the input before using split(",").

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using regular expression for text-parsing tasks like this one. It's the best tool to parse texts. Example code to extract a list in txt file is below:

```
import re

with open('test.txt', 'rb') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    pattern = '"(.*?)"' # this means: any characters between double quotation marks
    ignored = re.findall(pattern , line) # this method returns a list of strings that match pattern
```

Some assumptions in the code above:

- Your txt file is called test.txt which has only 1 line and that line holds the list.
- Your list is a list of strings each stays inside a pair of double quotation marks.

`re` is a built-in modules in Python, so there's no need to install any third-party library. More about regular expression can be found in [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it in the following way:

```
text1='''ignored = ["the", "a", "an", "i", "me", "you", "with", "this"]'''

list1=text1.split('[')[-1][:-1].replace('"','').split(',')
print(list1)
Out: ['the', ' a', ' an', ' i', ' me', ' you', ' with', ' this']
```

or with this

```
list1=text1.split('[')[-1].strip(']').replace('"','').split(',')
```

I just hard coded your text line to make it easy to test.

Answer (score 0):

ignored = ["the", "a", "an", "i", "me", "you", "with", "this"]

```
with open("ignored.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('ignored = ['):
            list = line.replace('ignored = [','').replace(']').replace('"', '').strip(',')
        print list
```

Answer (score -1):

use replace:

```
line.replace('"','').replace('[','') etc...
```